# How to rewrite this SELECT query

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

I've been left with some code that looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ee.* FROM exp_extensions ee WHERE enabled = 'y'
```

Our db admin is screaming about the select all, and wants us to grab all the individual fields separately. I've never seen a `SELECT DISTINCT *` before; how would I rewrite that?

Option 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ee.extension_id, ee.class, ee.method, ee.hook, ee.settings, ee.priority, ee.version, ee.enabled  FROM exp_extensions ee WHERE enabled = 'y'
```

Option 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (ee.extension_id, ee.class, ee.method, ee.hook, ee.settings, ee.priority, ee.version, ee.enabled)  FROM exp_extensions ee WHERE enabled = 'y'
```

Or some other way entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between Option 1 or Option 2.  Say you have a table that has one column `col1` that has one row.  *All* of these produce the same result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM t1
SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM t1
SELECT DISTINCT (col1) FROM t1
SELECT * FROM t1
SELECT col1 FROM t1
SELECT (col1) FROM t1
```

All the `*` does is essentially expand to all available columns on the table.